# How to use loop index variable inside command that will be invoked later

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

Let's consider the following code:

```
package require Tk

proc test {} {
    foreach n {
         1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
    } {
         pack [button ._$n -text $n -command {puts $n}]
    }
}

test
```

When one of the buttons invoked, "n" is unknown.

I found a away to address this by changing {puts $n} to "puts $n", but not sure this is a correct approach.

Comment: `[list puts $n]`?

Answer (score 0):

The callback for the button command is executed in the **global** scope, and there's no `n` variable there.

If you add `global n` command into that proc, then the error message won't appear, **but** each button will print the same value of n.

As you intent is to associate the value of `n` for each button, you need to pick a different quoting mechanism: braces prevent variable expansion. See https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/Tcl.htm -- Shawn's comment gave you the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind the current value of `$n` to the callback at the time you set it; your code as it stands uses whatever happens to be in the global `n` variable at the time that the callback is invoked (i.e., it is either the same for all the buttons or an error).

The `list` command is designed to be perfect for doing that binding; it generates a list, yes, but it also guarantees to generate a substitution-free command that has the words that are its arguments. That is, the script/command call:

```
eval [list $a $b $c]
```

is *guaranteed* to be the same as:

```
$a $b $c
```

for *any* values at all. This is an exceptionally useful property for almost any kind of code generation since it lets you make a script — that can be a call to a procedure for anything complicated — and pass any values over, entirely safely. In your case, this means that you should change change:

```
     pack [button ._$n -text $n -command {puts $n}]
```

to:

```
     pack [button ._$n -text $n -command [list puts $n]]
```

Comment: The last fix to enable this was a technical tweak to `#` handling in the first argument of lists in 8.4, but the semantics of this were intended from the very beginning; `list` has been documented to work like this back as far as we've got archive versions of the Tcl sources.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers!

I ended up with the following possible ways:

`"puts $n"` - good for simple cases, but a bit non-intuitive

`[list puts $n]` - good, especially for lists

`[subst {puts $n}]` - good, straightforward substitution